# BMX Bike Sizing and Changing Parts?

Tags: bmx, new-rider

I'm a 4'11" (150 cm) tall girl who just started riding BMX, and I'm riding a 20.5" (52 cm) frame. I find that it's really big and quite heavy for someone my size. Is 20.5" too big or should I just suck it up and keep going?

Also, if I were to get something smaller, can I just change the frame and use the existing tyres etc?

Comment: What kind of BMX are we talking about? I'm assuming it is racing or park but frame size is going to be different dependent on such.

Comment: Are you still growing?

Answer (score 5):

20.5" is way to big. You likely want something more around 18.5".

There are a number of bmx bike sizing charts out on the net to help guide you. Two examples are:

- https://www.usabmx.com/tracks/1709/pages/492
- https://www.danscomp.com/serve/products%7Ccharts/riderchart.htm

Other items you'll want to consider changing in addition to the frame size are going to be crank length, stem length, bar rise and bar width. Assuming you bought a pre-built bike, likely they are all oversized (for you) on your current bike. You may even be better off with a different wheel size.

If you were to get a smaller frame and move parts over you would want to make sure the new frame used all the same sized parts. Specifically you would want to make sure the new frame used the same type/size of bottom bracket, headset, seat post, dropout and wheel.

Do you have access to a local bike shop that has someone knowledgeable about BMX racing on staff? If so it might be worth stopping by and having a conversation with them.

Comment: Don't forget about rear-triangle size too, this has an affect on your "loopiness", shorter rear makes it easier to get into a "manual" position (Wheelie) which takes less effort to jump, especially if you are a smaller rider, but the longer rear is more stable so you don't loop out if you land too far back after a "dead sailor". This preference comes down to how you ride, but often overlooked by new riders. _(Note, for non racers: shorter front end helps you do nose wheelies)_